# Build Powershell String Parameter From Pipeline

Tags: powershell

I need to dynamically build a string parameter using output from a pipe which is then passed to another command.

The source command is `Get-VM` which has an element called Name

The destination command is `Move-VM`, which accepts a parameter of `-DestinationStoragePath`

I need to dynamically manipulate this path based on the source Name to be `D:\{0}` where `{0}` is the VM Name.

I have this so far:

```
Get-VM | Move-VM -DestinationStoragePath [string]::Format("D:\{0}",$_.Name)
```

But it is throwing an exception, if i statically set the DestinationStoragePath parameter, then it works fine, so its just this little bit that is tripping it up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Get-VM | Move-VM -DestinationStoragePath [string]::Format("D:{0}",$_.Name)
```

is trying to pass the string `[string]::Format("D:{0}",$_.Name)` literally to the parameter `-DestinationStoragePath`.

What you need is execute the expression and return the result by surrounding your expression in parenthesis like this:

```
Get-VM | % { Move-VM -DestinationStoragePath ([string]::Format("D:{0}",$_.Name)) }
```

Comment: was so close! This has fixed the problem, but i am now getting another issue with $_.Name being null. Has it been piped corrected from Get-VM?

Comment: I'm not awake. Updated in answer. I forgot the Foreach-object.